# How to make Html table responsive with screen size?

Tags: html, css, web, mobile-website

Can any help me to make this code responsive on phone, so that the table will change its size accordingly and will appear properly on mobile displays. The table is broken or cut in half with certain screen sizes

```
<style>
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  table {
    width: 100%;
  }
  th, td {
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 10px;
  }
}


table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 40%; 
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid black; 
  padding: 8px;
}

th {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: black; 
  text-align: left; 
}


td:nth-child(1) {
    width: 40%;
    text-align: left; 
}


td:nth-child(2) {
    width: 20%;
    text-align: right; 
}

td:nth-child(3) {
    width: 20%;
    text-align: right; 
}

tr:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
tr:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

tr:nth-child(odd) {
background-color: #ffffff;
}



</style>
<table>
<tr>
    <th colspan="3">Supplement Facts</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="3"style="background-color: #f2f2f2;">Supplement Facts</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="3" >Serving Size : 1 softgel</th>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <th colspan="3" style="background-color: #f2f2f2;">Supplement Facts: 120 </th>
  </tr>
    <td></td>
    <td> Amount per serving</td>
    <td>%Daily Value</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Calories</td>
    <td> 10</td>
    <td> 10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Total Fat</td>
    <td> 10</td>
    <td> 10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
 <td>Cholesterol</td>
    <td> 10</td>
    <td> 10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Krill Oil Concentrate</td>
    <td> 10</td>
    <td> 10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Phospholipids</td>
    <td>10 </td>
    <td> 10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Omega 3 Fatty Acids</td>
    <td> 10</td>
    <td> 10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>EPA (eicosapentaenoic acid)</td>
    <td> 10</td>
    <td> 10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>DHA (docosahexaenoic acid)</td>
    <td> 10</td>
    <td> 10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Astaxanthin</td>
    <td> 10</td>
    <td> 10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Omega 3 Fatty Acids</td>
    <td> 10</td>
    <td> 10</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

`

I tried 10 codes and some work on some sites others dont.
Trying to make table that is responsive on mobile.

Comment: add media query at the end of style tag

Comment: does not work...

Comment: <td></td>
    <td> Amount per serving</td> your tr tag missing before this

Answer (score -1):

[image] It's showing like this on 600px where you add media query. In down snippet I add media query on 768px which is use for mobile.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<style>

table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 40%; 
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid black; 
  padding: 8px;
}

th {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: black; 
  text-align: left; 
}


td:nth-child(1) {
    width: 40%;
    text-align: left; 
}


td:nth-child(2) {
    width: 20%;
    text-align: right; 
}

td:nth-child(3) {
    width: 20%;
    text-align: right; 
}

tr:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
tr:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

tr:nth-child(odd) {
background-color: #ffffff;
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  table {
    width: 100%;
  }
  th, td {
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 10px;
  }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<table>
<tr>
    <th colspan="3">Supplement Facts</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="3"style="background-color: #f2f2f2;">Supplement Facts</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="3" >Serving Size : 1 softgel</th>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <th colspan="3" style="background-color: #f2f2f2;">Supplement Facts: 120 </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td> Amount per serving</td>
    <td>%Daily Value</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Calories</td>
    <td> 10</td>
    <td> 10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Total Fat</td>
    <td> 10</td>
    <td> 10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
 <td>Cholesterol</td>
    <td> 10</td>
    <td> 10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Krill Oil Concentrate</td>
    <td> 10</td>
    <td> 10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Phospholipids</td>
    <td>10 </td>
    <td> 10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Omega 3 Fatty Acids</td>
    <td> 10</td>
    <td> 10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>EPA (eicosapentaenoic acid)</td>
    <td> 10</td>
    <td> 10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>DHA (docosahexaenoic acid)</td>
    <td> 10</td>
    <td> 10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Astaxanthin</td>
    <td> 10</td>
    <td> 10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Omega 3 Fatty Acids</td>
    <td> 10</td>
    <td> 10</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```